# Sequence question from Rudin

Tags: analysis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In this case, does $\{x_n\}$ converge given that $\{x_{2m}\}$ and $\{x_{2m+1}\}$ converge?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95368/in-this-case-does-x-n-converge-given-that-x-2m-and-x-2m1)

Fix $\alpha > 1$. Take $x_1 > \sqrt{\alpha}$, and define

$$x_{n + 1} = \frac{\alpha + x_n}{1 + x_n} = x_n + \frac{\alpha - x_n^2}{1 + x_n}.$$

(a) Prove that $x_1 > x_3 > x_5 > \cdots$.

(b) Prove that $x_2 < x_4 < x_6 < \cdots$.

(c) Prove that $\lim x_n = \sqrt{\alpha}$.

I think once I get (a), I will be able to solve the rest of the problem. However, I have tried a few different things and I can't seem to figure it out.

As suggested below
$$ x_{n + 2} = \frac{2 \alpha + (1 + \alpha)x_n}{(1 + \alpha) + 2x_n}$$

Another idea I had using the second form of the equation was to write $x_{n + 1}$ as

$$ x_{n + 1} = x_1 + \sum_{k = 1}^n f(k) $$
where 
$$f(k) = \frac{\alpha - x_k^2}{1 + x_k}$$

But once again I don't see where to go.

I've been looking at the problem Martin posted and this is what I have gotten.

Since $x_1 > \sqrt{\alpha}$, so $x_1 = \sqrt{\alpha} + \epsilon$.

$$x_2 = \frac{\alpha + x_1}{1 + x_1} 
= \frac{\alpha + \sqrt{\alpha}(1 + \epsilon)}{1 + \sqrt{\alpha}(1 + \epsilon} = \sqrt{\alpha}\left( \frac{\sqrt{\alpha} + 1 + \epsilon}{\sqrt{\alpha} + 1 + \sqrt{\alpha}\epsilon} \right) \le \sqrt{\alpha}\left( 1 - \left( \frac{\sqrt{\alpha} - 1}{\sqrt{\alpha} + 1} \right)\epsilon \right)$$

Then they use 3/2, but I dont see a way to base that on $\alpha$ instead.

Comment: Perhaps a good start would be to get a formula for $x_{n+2}$ in terms of $x_n$.

Comment: This is one of the many thing I tried, I just don't see where I can go with it.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the sequence defined [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60325/approximation-to-sqrt2) is a special case of your sequence.

Comment: that problem definitely is a special case of mine. Still having issues. Ill continue reading stuff.

Comment: Have you written out $x_{n + 2} - x_n$? It looks helpful.

Comment: You can show by induction that $\{x_{2k+1}\}$ is bounded below by $\sqrt{\alpha}$ and $\{x_{2k}\}$ is bounded above by $\sqrt{\alpha}$ from this you can then use the formula you get for $x_{n+2} - x_n$ (as Dylan suggested) to show that the sequences are increasing and decreasing respectively, part (c) should not be too hard after this either.

Comment: Take your formula for $x_{n+2}$ and use it to show that if $x_n\gt\sqrt\alpha$ then $x_n\gt x_{n+2}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the begining
$$
x_2-\sqrt{\alpha}=\frac{(\sqrt{\alpha}+x_1)(1-\sqrt{\alpha})}{1+x_1}<0
$$
i.e. $x_2<\sqrt{\alpha}$.
Now note that
$$
x_{n+2}-\sqrt{\alpha}=\frac{(x_n-\sqrt{\alpha})(\sqrt{\alpha}-1)^2}{1+\alpha+x_n}
$$
$$
x_{n+2}-x_n=2\frac{\alpha-x_n^2}{1+\alpha+2x_n}
$$
If $x_n>\sqrt{\alpha}$ then $x_{n+2}>\sqrt{\alpha}$. Hence for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we have $x_{2n-1}>\sqrt{\alpha}$. Then from the second inequality we obtain $x_{2n+1}<x_{2n-1}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

If $x_n<\sqrt{\alpha}$ then $x_{n+2}<\sqrt{\alpha}$. Hence for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we have $x_{2n}<\sqrt{\alpha}$. Then from the second inequality we obtain $x_{2n+2}>x_{2n}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.