# On the convergence of $a_n = 1 +\frac{1}{a_{n-1}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Question: Let $a_n$ be a sequence given by a starting seed $s$, with
$$ a_0 = s$$
an
$$ a_n = 1 + \frac{1}{a_{n-1}} $$
Does $a_n$ converge for every $s \in \mathbb{R}$?

---

This question comes from the fraction tower $1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+...}}}$. By choosing a starting seed we may discuss the behavior (convergence) of the sequence $a_n$. Clearly if the sequence converges, it must be either $\phi$ or $\frac{-1}{\phi}$. Using ratio test
$$\left|\frac{a_n - a_{n-1}}{a_{n-1} - a_{n-2}}\right| = \left|\frac{-1}{a_{n-2}+1}\right|$$
I found out that $\phi$ is the only possible solution except when $s=\frac{-1}{\phi}$(in which case would imply that $a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}$ would be $0$ for some $n$, and imply that the sequence is precisely $a_n = \frac{-1}{\phi}$.). But I have yet to prove that any starting seed $s \in \mathbb{R}$ except $\frac{-1}{\phi}$ would induce a convergent sequence (but I found some posts on MSE only discuss the convergence of the case where $s=1$ using the monotonicity).

How can I prove the statement above? (or is it correct?) Thanks in advance.

---

Some $s$ would make some term of the sequence undefined, namely $0, -1, -\frac{1}{2}, ...$, so one should exclude these cases.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convergence of $a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{1+a_n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/38739/convergence-of-a-n1-frac11a-n) See also [Why does this process, when iterated, tend towards a certain number? (the golden ratio?)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7266).

Comment: If $s = 0$, $a_1$ is undefined, so you should specify that $s \neq 0$.

Comment: @AnneBauval  The questions to which you linked only consider $s > 0$.  This question also considers $s < 0$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I agree. Concerning your previous comment, $s=0$ (and other forbidden values) were already excluded at the end of the present post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by discussing case by case:

Case 1: $s>0$. This can be done by discussing the monotonicity of the odd and even terms of $a_n$.

Case 2: It can be seen that $(-\infty, -1)$ will map to a positive number in 1 time.
$(-1/2, 0)$ can be map to positive number in 2 times, $(-1, \frac{-2}{3})$ will map to positive in 3, etc. These numbers (namely $0, \frac{-1}{2}, \frac{-2}{3}, \frac{-3}{5}, ...$ given by the (negative) quotient of adjacent terms of fibonacci sequence $F_n$) converges to $\frac{-1}{\phi}$ and thus let

$$ u_n = -\frac{F_{n}}{F_{n+1}} = \{-1, \frac{-1}{2}, \frac{-2}{3}, \frac{-3}{5}, ...\}$$
then let
$I_0 = (u_2, 0), I_1= (u_1, u_3), I_2 = (u_4, u_2), I_4 = (u_3, u_5)$ etc we have
$ \bigcup I_n = (-1, 0) \setminus \{u_n\}$ and hence choosing any points except points in $u_n$ will eventually make $a_n$ converge(and as for $s=u_n$, $a_n$ would be undefined for some term).

Comment: (+1) I found the same, thanks to Qiaochu Yuan's (incomplete) last comment in [his answer to the 2nd proposed duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/7275).