# Proof of Convergence: Babylonian Method $x_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}(x_n + \frac{a}{x_n})$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, recurrence-relations, radicals

a) Let $a>0$ and the sequence $x_n$ fulfills $x_1>0$ and $x_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}(x_n + \frac{a}{x_n})$ for $n \in \mathbb N$. Show that $x_n \rightarrow \sqrt a$ when $n\rightarrow \infty$.

I have done it in two ways, but I guess I'm not allowed to use the first one and the second one is incomplete. Can someone please help me?

1. We already know $x_n \rightarrow \sqrt a$, so we do another step of the iteration and see that $x_{n+1} = \sqrt a$.
2. Using limit, $x_n \rightarrow x, x_{n+1} \rightarrow x$ (this is the part I think it's incomplete, don't I have to show $x_{n+1} \rightarrow x$, how?), we have that

$$x = \frac x 2 (1 + \frac a {x^2}) \Rightarrow 1 = a/x^2 \Rightarrow x = \sqrt a$$

b) Let the sequence $x_n$ be defined as $x_{n+1}= 1 + \frac 1 {x_n} (n \in \mathbb N), x_1=1$. Show that it converges and calculate its limit.

"Tip: Show that sequences $x_{2n}$ and $x_{2n+1}$ monotone convergent to the limit."
I didn't understand the tip, how can this help me? Does it make a difference if the number is odd or even?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This link might be useful for a: http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Iterative_Process_for_Estimating_Square_Roots

Comment: When you (or someone) cleverly noticed that $x_n=\frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n}$, where $F_n$ is the $n$-th term of Fibonacci sequence, you could use show this by induction. Then you can find $x_{n+1}-x_n=\frac{F_{n+2}}{F_{n+1}}-\frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n}=\frac{F_nF_{n+2}-F_{n+1}}{F_nF_{n+1}}=(-1)^{n+1}\frac1{F_nF_{n+1}}$, using [Cassini's identity](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Cassini%27s_Identity). This means that the sequence is alternating and that $\frac1{|x_n-x_{n+1}|}\to0$. \\ This is basically the suggestions from Aryabhata's answer.

Comment: In (a), it actually turns out you can give an explicit solution to the recurrence: there exists some $\theta_0$ such that $a_n = \sqrt{a} \coth(2^n \theta_0)$ for $n \ge 2$.  (Leaving this as a comment since the methods in the existing answers are much more useful in general.)

Comment: See this [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4766087/432081) and its comment.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

(a) Yes, you need to show first that $\langle x_n\rangle_n$ is convergent; once you know that, your argument shows that its limit must be $\sqrt a$. You might want to look first at the discussion below for (b).

(b) Yes, it does make a difference whether $n$ is odd or even. Calculate the first few values: $$x_1=1, x_2 = 2,x_3=\frac32,x_4=\frac53,x_5=\frac85,x_6=\frac{13}8.$$ Note that the sequence is oscillating: the odd-numbered terms are low, and the even-numbered terms are high. On the other hand, $x_1<x_3<x_5$, and $x_2>x_4>x_6$. This suggests that the sequence does converge to some limit $x$ in such a way that $$x_1<x_3<x_5<\dots <x<\dots<x_6<x_4<x_2\;.$$

If you can show that $x_{2n+1}<x_{2n+3}<x_2$ for all $n\ge 0$, you’ll know that the sequence of odd-numbered is monotone increasing and bounded above, which implies that it converges to some $x_{\text{odd}}$. Similarly, if you can show that $x_1<x_{2n+2}<x_{2n}$ for every $n\ge 1$, you’ll know that the sequence of even-numbered terms is monotone decreasing and bounded below, which implies that it converges to some $x_{\text{even}}$. Then you’ll have to find a way to show that $x_{\text{odd}}=x_{\text{even}}$.

(By the way, the terms of this sequence are the ratios of consecutive Fibonacci numbers, and their limit is $\varphi = \frac12(1+\sqrt 5)$.)

**Added:** After some algebra we get $$x_{n+2}=1+\frac1{x_{n+1}}=1+\left(1+\frac1{x_n}\right)^{-1}=\frac{2x_n+1}{x_n+1}$$ and $$x_{n+4}=\frac{5x_n+3}{3x_n+2}\;.$$ Thus,

$$\begin{align*}
x_{n+4}<x_{n+2}&\text{ iff } \frac{5x_n+3}{3x_n+2}<\frac{2x_n+1}{x_n+1}\\
&\text{ iff }5x_n^2+8x_n+3<6x_n^2+7x_n+2\\
&\text{ iff }0<x_n^2-x_n-1\\
&\text{ iff }2x_n+1<x_n^2+x_n\\
&\text{ iff }x_{n+2}<x_n
\end{align*}\tag{1}$$

Since $x_4=\frac53<2=x_2$, it follows by induction from $(1)$ that $\langle x_{2n}:n\in\mathbb{Z}^+\rangle$ is a decreasing sequence. The calculation in $(1)$ remains valid if all of the inequalities are turned around, and $x_3=\frac32>1=x_1$, so essentially the same induction shows that $\langle x_{2n-1}:n\in\mathbb{Z}^+\rangle$ is a decreasing sequence.

Now let $\varphi=\frac12(1+\sqrt 5)$, the positive zero of $x^2-x-1$. Note that if $x$ is a positive real number, $x>\varphi$ iff $x^2-x-1>0$. Moreover,

$$\begin{align*}
x_{n+2}^2-x_{n+2}-1&=\left(\frac{2x_n+1}{x_n+1}\right)^2-\frac{2x_n+1}{x_n+1}-1\\
&=\frac{x_n^2-x_n-1}{(x_n+1)^2}\;,
\end{align*}$$

and $(x_n+1)^2>0$, so $x_{n+2}^2-x_{n+2}-1$ and $x_n^2-x_n-1$ have the same algebraic sign, and therefore $x_{n+2}>\varphi$ iff $x_n>\varphi$. Now $\varphi\approx 1.618$, so $x_2>\varphi$, and it follows by induction that $x_{2n}>\varphi$ for every $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$.

Similarly, $x<\varphi$ iff $x^2-x-1<0$ if $x$ is a positive real, and $x_1=1<\varphi$, so the same induction shows that $x_{2n-1}<\varphi$ for every $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$. Thus, $$x_1<x_3<x_5<\dots <\varphi<\dots<x_6<x_4<x_2\;.$$ In particular, the sequence of odd-numbered terms is increasing and bounded above by $\varphi$, and the sequence of even-numbered terms is decreasing and bounded below by $\varphi$, so both have limits. This doesn’t yet prove that both subsequences have the *same* limit, but we’re getting there.

There are several ways to finish the job. One is to let $L$ be the limit of one of the subsequences, say the even-numbered one. Then $$L=\lim_{n\to\infty}x_{2n+2}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2x_{2n}+1}{x_{2n}+1}=\frac{2L+1}{L+1}\;,$$ so $L^2+L=2L+1$, $L^2-L-1=0$, and $L=\varphi$ (since the negative solution is plainly wrong). A similar calculation takes care of the other subsequence.

Another approach is to consider $$\left|\frac{x_{n+2}-x_{n+1}}{x_{n+1}-x_n}\right|=\left|\frac{\frac{5x_n+3}{3x_n+2}-\frac{2x_n+1}{x_n+1}}{\frac{2x_n+1}{x_n+1}-x_n}\right|=\left|\frac1{3x_n+2}\right|=\frac1{3x_n+2}<\frac12,$$ since the $x_n$ are all positive. In other words, the gap between consecutive terms shrinks at least geometrically and therefore tends to $0$, so the two subsequences must actually have the same limit, and it must satisfy $L=\frac1{L+1}$.

Comment: hi brian, thanks for the reply. I think I have to prove this with induction, but I'm lost as to which step to do or what the beginning of the induction is. any tips?

Comment: @Clash: Induction looks good. Note that $x_{n+2}=1+\frac1{x_{n+1}}=1+\left(1+\frac1{x_n}\right)^{-1}=$  $1+\frac{x_n}{x_n+1}=\frac{2x_n+1}{x_n+1}$. When is $\frac{2x_n+1}{x_n+1}<x_n$, and when is $\frac{2x_n+1}{x_n+1}>x_n$? What is $x_{n+4}$ in terms of $x_n$? Try using this to show that if $x_{n+2}<x_n$, then $x_{n+4}<x_{n+2}$, and similarly for $>$.

Comment: Brian, I swear I'm trying to solve it since I posted. I just can't move forward. All I got was $x_{n+2} > x_n$, when $x_n^2 < x_n + 1$. As all the values are contained in [1, 2], I guess this does make some sense. I then reached your answer at $\varphi$. I suppose I'm trying to solve it with the wrong tools.

Comment: So, $x_{n+2} > x_n$ until $x_n < \varphi = \frac12(1+\sqrt 5)$?

Comment: @Clash: With a bit of algebra you get $x_{n+4}=\frac{5x_n+3}{3x_n+2}$, which is $>\frac{2x_n+1}{x_n+1}$ iff $x_n^2-x_n-1<0$, which is exactly the condition that you found was equivalent to $x_{n+2}>x_n$. Thus, $x_{n+4}>x_{n+2}$ iff $x_{n+2}>x_n$; since $x_1<x_3$, the fact that the odd-numbered terms are increasing follows by induction. Now do the same thing with $<$ and the even-numbered terms.

Comment: Hi Brian! Thanks for the great answer. I think I'm almost there. I did have your $x_{n+4}$, just didn't understand the relation. Thanks for clearing that up! I now have $x_{n+3}=\frac{3x_n+2}{2x_n+1}$ and $x_{n+5}=\frac{13x_n+8}{8x_n+5}$, which are both $<x_{n+1}$, when $x_n^2-x_n-1<0$. Therefore $x_{n+5} < x_{n+3} < x_{n+1}$. Did I get it right? Can I now simply do $x_n=x_{n+1}$ (since both converge) and get $\varphi$? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: wait, I didn't have to had to calculate $x_{n+3}$ and $x_{n+5}$, right? I could have just showed that $x_{n+4}<x_{n+2}<x_n$, when $x_n^2-x_n-1>0$. Is this right?

Comment: (sorry for the third comment in a row). I mean, if I have shown it's monotone and lower/upper bounded, I can write $x_{n+1}=x_n$, right? Then I'd get $\varphi = \frac12(1+\sqrt 5)$. btw small mistake, $x_{n+5}$ is actually $\frac{8x_n+5}{5x_n+3}$.

Comment: @Clash: Rather than respond in detail in the comments, I’ve gone ahead and completed the solution in the answer proper; you’ve clearly put thought into it at this point.

Comment: sadly I had to finish my exercise before I saw your reply, but wow! Thanks a lot, now it's 100% clear to me!

Comment: You are wrong that the sequence oscillates around $a$. AM/GM means that all $x_i$ are the average of two terms whose Geometric Mean is $\sqrt a$, so $x_i>\sqrt a$ for all $i>1$.

Answer (score 14):

**(a)** Your argument shows that, *if* the sequence ($x_n$) *converges*, its limit must be $\sqrt{a}$. To show it in fact converges to $\sqrt{a}$, we note that

$$\begin{align*}x_{n+1}-\sqrt{a}
&=\frac12\left(x_n-\sqrt{a}+\frac{a}{x_n}-\sqrt{a}\right)\\
&=\frac12\left(1-\frac{\sqrt{a}}{x_n}\right)\left(x_n-\sqrt{a}\right)\\
&=\frac1{2x_n}(x_n-\sqrt{a})^2.
\end{align*}$$

Since we can show (by induction) that $x_n>0$ and $x_{n+1}\ge\sqrt{a}\ $ (for $n\ge 1$), we have

$$|x_{n+1}-\sqrt{a}|=\frac12\left|1-\frac{\sqrt{a}}{x_n}\right||x_n-\sqrt{a}|\le\frac12|x_n-\sqrt{a}|.\quad (n\ge 2)$$

Therefore $0\le |x_n-\sqrt{a}|\le \left(\frac12\right)^{n-2}|x_2-\sqrt{a}|$, and by the squeeze theorem we obtain $|x_n-\sqrt{a}|\to 0$.

**(b)** A similar argument can be used to show that, *if* the sequence ($x_n$) *converges*, its limit $\alpha$ must satisfy $\alpha=1+\frac1{\alpha}$. Since we can show (by induction) $x_n>0$, $\alpha=\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}$, not $\frac{1-\sqrt5}{2}$.

To show that it in fact converges to $\alpha$, we note that
$$\begin{align*}
x_{n+1}-\alpha=\frac1{x_n}-\frac1{\alpha}=-\frac{1}{\alpha x_n}(x_n-\alpha).
\end{align*}$$

Since we can show (by induction) that $x_n\ge 1$, we have

$$|x_{n+1}-\alpha|=\left|\frac1{\alpha x_n}\right||x_n-\alpha|\le \frac1{\alpha}|x_n-\alpha|\quad \text{with}\quad 0<\frac1{\alpha}<1.$$

Therefore $0\le |x_n-\alpha|\le \left(\frac1\alpha\right)^{n-1}|x_1-\alpha|$, and by the squeeze theorem we obtain $|x_n-\alpha|\to 0$.

(P.S. It is true that "$x_{2n}$ and $x_{2n+1}$ are monotone convergent to the limit", but it is not necessary to show it here.)

Answer (score 9):

Extended from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/126981/) to a deleted question.

Note that all $x_n>0$ and
$$
x_{n+1}^2=\frac14\left(x_n+\frac{a}{x_n}\right)^2=\frac14\left(x_n-\frac{a}{x_n}\right)^2+a\ge a\tag{1}
$$
Thus, all $x_n$ past the first satisfy $x_n^2\ge a$. Therefore,
$$
x_{n+1}-x_n=\frac{a-x_n^2}{2x_n}\le0\tag{2}
$$
says that $x_{n+1}\le x_n$. Therefore, $\{x_n\}$ is a decreasing sequence, bounded below. Thus, the sequence converges. Furthermore, since the sequence converges,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}a-x_n^2=\lim_{n\to\infty}2x_n(x_{n+1}-x_n)=0\tag{3}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n^2=a\tag{4}
$$

Comment: The proof of (4) holds up under the rational numbers.

Comment: @MikeMathMan: I am not sure what you mean. Are you saying there is a problem in the answer?

Comment: No. I love your proof! Just meant that it even works if your domain of discourse is the rational numbers. What is the motivation /insight for writing down (1)?  If standard technique, where else? If original and yours - brilliant!

Comment: @robjohn I really like this proof, much better than the others I have seen. I'm stuck with part (3) however, could you please help me understand it?

Comment: @Daniele1234: Multiply $x_{n+1}-x_n=\frac{a-x_n^2}{2x_n}$ by $2x_n$.

Comment: @robjohn Then how does one conclude limn→∞2xn(xn+1−xn)=0

Comment: @Daniele1234: the sequence decreases, so $x_n\le x_1$, and the sequence converges, so $x_{n+1}-x_n\to0$.

Comment: @robjohn And can one show $x_{n+1}-x_n\to0$ without the Cauchy Criterion (all I know now is MCT and BWT)?

Comment: @Daniele1234: it was shown that since $x_n$ is monotonically decreasing and bounded below, $x_n$ converges. This immediately gives that $x_{n+1}-x_n\to0$.

Comment: @robjohn I understand that by MCT $x_n$ converges, but to claim that $x_{n+1}-x_n\to0$ is true requires the Cauchy Criterion or am I wrong - can you derive that using only Axiom of Completeness/MCT/etc

Comment: @Daniele1234: [a sequence of real numbers which is monotonically decreasing and bounded below is convergent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem#Convergence_of_a_monotone_sequence_of_real_numbers)

Comment: @robjohn Yes Monotone Convergence Theorem as I said.... However, why does it being convergent allow you to rigorously claim that $x_{n+1}-x_n\to0$?

Comment: @Daniele1234: Consider [the property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_sequence#Properties) that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(x_{n+1}-x_n\right)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_{n+1}-\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n$. Alternatively, you could use [the definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_sequence#Formal_definition) and [the triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality).

Comment: Unbelievable. I think I spent 4 hours stuck on this problem and didn't see (1). Pisses me off that I can't see things like that.

Answer (score 3):

For **a)** a simple proof exists and can be generalized to the sequence 
$$K x_{n+1}  = (K-1)x_n + \frac{a}{x_n^{K-1}}$$

which converges to $\sqrt[K]{a}$ (your sequence has $K=2$).

Use $\text{AM} \ge \text{GM}$ to show that

$x_{n+1} \ge \sqrt{a}$.

Now
$x_{n+1} - x_n = \frac{a - x_n^2}{2x_n} \le 0$ as $x_n \ge \sqrt{a}$ for $n \gt 1$.

Thus the sequence is monotonically decreasing (starting from $n=2$) and bounded below and so converges.

For **b)** refer to various proofs here: [Why does this process, when iterated, tend towards a certain number? (the golden ratio?)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7266/why-does-this-process-when-iterated-tend-towards-a-certain-number-the-golden)

(The link above applies to $y_n = \frac{1}{x_n}$).

Comment: what's AM and GM?

Comment: @Clash http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means

Answer (score 3):

AM-GM inequality tells us, $$x_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}\left(x_n+\dfrac{a}{x_n}\right) \ge \sqrt{x_n.\frac{a}{x_n}}=\sqrt{a}.$$ In other words, $\{x_2, x_3, x_4, \cdots\}$ is bounded below by $\sqrt{a}.$
Also, this implies that $$x_{n+1}-x_{n+2}=x_{n+1}-\dfrac12\left(x_{n+1}+\dfrac{a}{x_{n+1}}\right)=\dfrac{x_{n+1}^2-a}{2x_{n+1}}\ge0.$$ Therefore $x_2\ge x_3\ge x_4\ge\cdots.$

By the Monotone Convergent Theorem $\lim_{n \to \infty}x_n=l$ is exist as a real number and $$l=\dfrac12\left(l+\dfrac{a}{l}\right).$$

Comment: Nice steps....So you are telling that $\{x_n\}$ is monotonically decreasing to $\sqrt a$, right? Could you pls justify. Also, what happen when $x_1 < \sqrt a$.

Comment: @Riaz: We have not used any property of $x_1,$ other than $x_1>0.$ Hope my edit makes it clear.

Comment: Lovely and elegant proof, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For **a)**:

The proof of convergence can be deduced from the question/answer LFT theory found in

[Iterative Convergence Formulation for Linear Fractional Transformation with Rational Coefficients](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2240119/iterative-convergence-formulation-for-linear-fractional-transformation-with-rati)

**Proof when $x_1^2 > a$**

Note: If both $a$ and $x_1$ are rational numbers, then this solution is obtained  without recourse to the real number system.

Let $S$ represent $a$ and $K$ denote $x_1$.

We have our LFT theory for

## $F(x) = \frac{S + Kx}{K + x}$

as espoused in the above link.

Considering Proposition 2 & 3, we have a sequence

$\{F^1, F^2, F^3, ..., F^n, ...\}$ of LFTs

with the corresponding decreasing sequence of Ks

$\{K, K_2, K_3, ..., K_n, ...\}$ and $(K_n)^2$ converges to $S$.

Might as well set $K_1$ to $K$ now.

Now with a little thought, you can see the following holds:

$K_2 = (S + K_1^2)/2K_1$

$K_4 = (S + K_2^2)/2K_2$

$K_8 = (S + K_4^2)/2K_4$

$K_{16} = (S + K_8^2)/2K_8$

etc.

But this is exactly the Babylonian Method.

So the method can  actually be described as calculating numbers that are a subsequence of our convergent sequence

$\{K_1, K_2, K_3, ..., K_n, ...\}$

So we have shown that the squares of the numbers produced by the Babylonian Method converge to $S$.

**Proof when $x_1^2 < a$**

Let $K$ denote $(a + x_1^2)/2x_1$. We know by the LFT theory that the square of this number is greater than $a$. So, the proof given above can now be applied, by simply 'throwing out' the first number $x_1$ of the sequence.

Answer (score 1):

For **b):**

Consider the function,

## $F(x) = 1 + 1/x$.

If you set $F(x)$ to the identity function $x$ and solve for $x$ using the quadratic formula, you will see that $F(x)$ has two fixed points, one positive and one negative.

With a little thought you might guess that our sequence is converging to the positive fixed point,

$\alpha=\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}$.

Notice that we can restrict the domain of $F(x)$ and analyze the decreasing function

$F: [1.5,\,  2] \to [1.5,\,  2]$

Let $u$ and $v$ be any two distinct points in the closed interval $[1.5,\,  2]$.

Then

## $\frac{(F(v) - F(u))}{(v - u)}$

is equal to (algebra)

## $\frac {-1}{uv}$

The absolute value of this number can be no larger than

$\frac {1}{1.5*1.5}$, which is equal to $\frac {4}{9}$.

Applying the [Banach Fixed Point Theorem,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem)

we see that our sequence $x_{n+1}= 1 + \frac 1 {x_n} (n \in \mathbb N^*), x_1=1$ converges to $\alpha$, since $F(x_1)$ is 2.

*Addendum*

Actually, for our situation, we don't have to use Banach's theorem. One can easily prove the following, which can also be used to prove convergence of our sequence $x_1, x_2, x_3, ...,$.

Proposition: Let $f(x)$ be a continuous strictly monotonic function mapping a closed interval

$I = [a,\, b]$

into itself.

Assume that there is exactly one fixed point $c$ for $f$ with $a < c < b$.

Then for all $n > 0$, $f^n(I)$ is a closed interval that contains $c$, with $c$ not an endpoint.

Suppose also there is positive $\lambda < 1$, such that for any $\alpha$ $\beta$ with $a < \alpha < \beta < b$, the absolute value of

## $\frac{(f(\beta) - f(\alpha))}{(\beta - \alpha)}$

is less than $\lambda$.

Then the intersection, $\cap \, f^n(I) \, | \, n > 0$, contains only one point, $c$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution with closed-form formula for $x_n$.
We notice that
$$x_{n+1}-\sqrt{a} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x_n-\sqrt{a} }{\sqrt{x_n}}  \right)^2 \tag{1}$$
$$x_{n+1}+\sqrt{a}  = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x_n+\sqrt{a} }{\sqrt{x_n}}  \right)^2\tag{2}$$

From $(1),(2)$ we have

$$\frac{x_{n+1}-\sqrt{a}  }{x_{n+1}+\sqrt{a}  }= \left(\frac{x_n-\sqrt{a} }{x_n+\sqrt{a} }  \right)^2=...=\left(\frac{x_1-\sqrt{a}}{x_1+\sqrt{a}}  \right)^{2^n} \tag{3}$$

From $(3)$ you deduce the closed form solution of $x_n$:
$$x_n =\sqrt{a} +2\sqrt{a}\cdot \frac{\left(x_1-\sqrt{a}  \right)^{2^n}}{\left(x_1+\sqrt{a}  \right)^{2^n}-\left(x_1-\sqrt{a}  \right)^{2^n}}$$

From that, it's easy to show that, $a_n  \to \sqrt{a}$ when $n\to +\infty$ as the second term tends to $0$.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to prove the Babylonian method works is to think of it as like [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method), but faster.

With each $x_n$, associate the *closed interval* $I_n$ between $x_n$ and $\frac {a}{x_n}$, inclusive. Let the left and right bounds of this interval be $l_n$ and $r_n$ respectively. (We can and will safely assume throughout this answer that $x_n \ne \sqrt a$ and thus $l_n < r_n$ for all $n$, since proving the method works in the special case where $x_n = \sqrt a$ is trivial.) Note that $I_n$ always contains both $x_n$ (by definition) and $\sqrt a$. Consider the size of the $(n+1)$th such interval, $s_{n+1} = r_{n+1} - l_{n+1}$. This is less than half the size of the previous interval, $s_n$.

To see this, note that by definition $x_{n+1}$ is the *midpoint* of the $n$th interval. Hence the intervals $[l_n, x_{n+1}]$ and $[x_{n+1}, r_n]$ both have a size of exactly $\frac {s_n}{2}$. Interval $I_n = [l_{n+1}, r_{n+1}]$ must actually be even smaller than this, since if $x_{n+1} = l_{n+1} > l_n$ then $r_{n+1} = \frac {a}{l_{n+1}} < \frac {a}{l_n} = r_n$, and if $x_{n+1} = r_{n+1} < r_n$ then $l_{n+1} = \frac {a}{r_{n+1}} > \frac {a}{r_n} = l_n$.

The maximum difference between $x_n$ and $\sqrt a$ is $s_n$, the size of the interval $I_n$ that contains them both. But the size of that interval, $s_{n} <= \frac {s_1} {2^{n-1}}$ tends to 0 as $n \rightarrow \infty$. Thus $|x_n - \sqrt a| \rightarrow 0$, or, equivalently, $x_n \rightarrow \sqrt a$.