# Computing square roots to specified accuracy

Tags: arithmetic

How do I get the square root of a number (3 in this case) that is accurate to a specified number of digits to the right of the decimal point?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots

Comment: For Newton's method, see [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/309082/computing-the-square-root-function-with-newtons-method)

Answer (score 1):

Since Ross added an answer, I felt free to add my own. In the antedeluvian days when I was a schoolboy, this was part of the high school curriculum. One particular technique (out of many in the Wikipedia link Billy provided) is explained pretty well [here](http://www.basic-mathematics.com/square-root-algorithm.html) It's similar in shape to the long division algorithm that I still hope is taught today. Using it you can just crank out as many digits of the square root as necessary. BTW $\sqrt{3}\approx1.732050807568877$.

Answer (score 0):

Just so we have an answer see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots) and for Newton's method see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/309082/computing-the-square-root-function-with-newtons-method)