# To show sequence $a_{n+1}= \frac{a_n^2+1}{2 (a_n+1)}$ is convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

Let $a_1=0$ 
 and $$a_{n+1}= \dfrac{a_n^2+1}{2 (a_n+1)}$$ $\forall n> 1.$
 Show that sequence $a_n$ convergent.

I tried to prove $a_n$ is less than 1 by looking at few terms. But i failed to prove my claim.

Comment: What did you try already ?

Comment: @Claude I tried to p r ove $a_n $ is less than 1 by looking at few terms .but i failed toprove my claim which is why i posted , please donot downvote

Comment: I shall not downvote, be sure ! And now, you received an answer. So, I stop thinking !! Cheers :-)

Comment: @SophieClad try to prove that it is decreasing.

Comment: I shall try perhaps later to write an answer. Right now MathJax is making problems and every two second the answer gets uncoded, making it unbelievably annoying and hard to write decently.

Comment: I used the quotient ceiterium and got: $ 1/2 * ( 1/(a+1) + 1/(a^2 +a)) $ from there I would not know how to go further to prove this term is always less than 1..
Can someone offer a solution solution (?)

Comment: $$a_{n+1} - a_n = \frac{a_n^2 +1}{2(a_n + 1)} -a_n = -\frac{a_n^2 + 2a_n -1}{2(a_n + 1)}$$
So this iteration is the [Newton method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) to solve $f(x) = x^2 + 2x -1 = 0$. Then verify the convergence condition for this method

Comment: @SophieClad: Note that $$a_{n+1}+1=\dfrac{1}{2}\Big((a_n+1)+\dfrac{2}{(a_n+1)}\Big)$$ Now you can take another solution from [here.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82682/proof-of-convergence-babylonian-method-x-n1-frac12x-n-fracax-n)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clearly $a_n\ge 0\forall n.$ $$a_{n+1}= \dfrac{a_n^2+1}{2 (a_n+1)}$$ $$a_n^2-2a_na_{n+1}+(1-2a_{n+1})=0$$ This is a quadratic equation of $a_n.$ Since $a_n\in\mathbb{R}$ we have $$4a_{n+1}^2-4(1-2a_{n+1})\ge 0$$ $$(a_{n+1}+1)^2\ge 2$$ Hence $$a_{n+1}\ge \sqrt{2}-1.$$ Now consider $$a_{n+1}-a_n=\dfrac{-a_n^2-2a_n+1}{2 (a_n+1)}=-\dfrac{(a_n+1+\sqrt{2})(a_n+1-\sqrt{2})}{2 (a_n+1)}\le 0.$$ Therefore $a_n$ is decreasing and bounded below for $n\ge 2$.

Comment: Take $x=50$... You have to prove the inequality by induction.

Comment: @Nilan can you explainlast step?

Comment: @Martigan: I have edited my answer without induction.

Comment: Nilan, I think the sequence is *decreasing* ...and anyway, the very last inequality in your post is unjustified **unless** you can prove both that $\;a_n\ge 0\;\;\;\forall n\;$ , and *also* that $\;a_n<-1+\sqrt2\;$ , which I think is false, btw.

Comment: @nilan, it is decreasing for $\;n\ge 2\;$. See my answer.

Comment: The step from $(1+a_{n+1})^2\geq2$ to $a_{n+1}\leq -1+\sqrt{2}$ is wrong.

Comment: @Michael Yes: upon taking square roots, absolute value must kick in.

Comment: Should it be $a_{n+1}\geq-1+\sqrt2$ or $a_{n+1}\leq-1-\sqrt2$?

Comment: @Michael Indeed. I arrived in my answer to these inequalities in what I think is a simpler way.

Comment: @nilan, again: after your "Hence", why is $\;a_n\ge 0\;$ ? Otherwise you can't discard the case $\;a_n\le -1-\sqrt2\;$

Comment: there is tiny window for things to get better. i hope it does.

Comment: @Nilan can you please explain last step

Comment: @abel what are you pointing at ?

Comment: @Nilan will this approach always work for real sequences .

Comment: @SophieClad, sorry. that was meant for nilan.

Comment: @abel should i first calculate its limit and then try to prove boundedness and decreasing , for these types of questions.also i havenot seen your comment

Comment: @SophieClad,  check out math110's solution below that is very cute. assuming the limit exists, you can find them by solving $L =\dfrac{L^2 + 1}{2(L+1)}.$ now find a difference equation for $b_n = L - a_n$ show that $b_n \to 0$

Answer (score 2):

since
$$a_{n+1}-(\sqrt{2}-1)=\dfrac{a^2_{n}+1-2(\sqrt{2}-1)(a_{n}+1)}{2a_{n}+2}=\dfrac{[a_{n}-(\sqrt{2}-1)]^2}{2a_{n}+2}\tag{1}$$
simaler
$$a_{n+1}+\sqrt{2}+1=\dfrac{(a_{n}+\sqrt{2}+1)^2}{2a_{n}+2}\tag{2}$$
$\dfrac{(1)}{(2)}$ we have

$$\dfrac{a_{n+1}-(\sqrt{2}-1)}{a_{n+1}+\sqrt{2}+1}=\left(\dfrac{a_{n}-(\sqrt{2}-1)}{a_{n}+\sqrt{2}+1}\right)^2=\cdots=\left(\dfrac{a_{0}-(\sqrt{2}-1)}{a_{0}+\sqrt{2}+1}\right)^{2^n}\to 0$$
beause
$$\dfrac{a_{0}-(\sqrt{2}-1)}{a_{0}+\sqrt{2}+1}<1$$
so
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n}=\sqrt{2}-1$$

Answer (score 2):

1) Clearly (add a little explanation here) the sequence is non-negative for all indexes

2) For $\;n\ge 2\;$ , the sequence is monotonic decreasing, since:

$$a_{n+1}\le a_n\iff \frac{a_n^2+1}{2(a_n+1)}\le a_n\iff a_n^2+2a_n-1\ge 0\iff$$

$$\iff (a_n+1+\sqrt2)(a_n+1-\sqrt2)\ge 0\iff\begin{cases}a_n\le -1-\sqrt2\\{}\\or\\{}\\a_n\ge-1+\sqrt2\end{cases}$$

The first case above is impossible, and the second one follows from

$$a_{n+1}\ge-1+\sqrt2\iff a_n^2+1\ge (2\sqrt2-2)a_n+2\sqrt2-2\iff$$

$$\iff a_n^2-2(\sqrt2-1)a_n-(2\sqrt2-3)\ge 0\iff (a_n+1-\sqrt2)^2\ge 0$$

and we're done since the last inequality is trivially true.

Now you can easily deduce the sequence converges, and its limit $\;x\;$ fulfills

$$x=\frac{x^2+1}{2(x+1)}\implies x=-1+\sqrt2$$

Comment: How did you know sequence is decreasing before proving it .How to think about thesetyoes of questions

Comment: @SophieClad I didn't before the proof: I calculate the first few elements and by taking into account the form of the sequence one makes "and educated guess". Next, the proof must come in.

Comment: but relation is for n greater than 1 .we cannot put 1 in it to get next terms

Comment: @SophieClad Yes... so? I don't get your point./

Comment: Point is how you calculated few terms of sequence

Comment: @SophieClad We're given $$a_1=0\implies a_2=\frac12\implies a_3=\frac{\left(\frac12\right)^2+1}{2\left(\frac12+1\right)}=\frac{\frac54}{2 \cdot\frac32}=\frac5{12}\;,\;\;\text{and etc.}$$ Still, I can't see your point...?

Comment: How have u got  a2 = 1\2 ¿ , recurrence relationis valid for n greater than 1 not for 1

Comment: @SophieClad But **you wrote** $\;a_1=0\;$ and then the recursive formula for $\;n>1\;$...read your own question again! And it *obviously* must be true also for $\;n+1=2\;$ , otherwise you *have no sequence at all* as you can **not** calculate even the first elements!