# Recursive Monotone Decreasing Sequence Proof ${x_{k}} = \frac{1}{2}\left({x_{k-1}+\frac{a}{{x_{k-1}}}}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, monotone-functions

I have been looking at this for hours and it isn't making anymore sense than it did in the first hour.

If $a$ und ${x_{0}}$ are positive real numbers and ${x_{k}}$ defined as follows, prove that ${x_{k}}$ is monotone decreasing and bounded, then calculate the limit.

${x_{k}} = \frac{1}{2}\left({x_{k-1}+\frac{a}{{x_{k-1}}}}\right)$

What I though I had to do was pick an ${x_{0}}$ and solve for ${x_{k}}$, so I picked ${x_{0}}$. Then I wanted to put the result back into the function to get ${x_{k+1}}$, which I still believe is what I'm supposed to be doing, but I don't understand what I am getting as a result. 
I get that I should prove it is decreasing,
then that it is bounded, 
then address the limit,
but the how is missing.

Comment: I will mention that you can find other posts about this sequence, see [Proof of Convergence: Babylonian Method $x_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}(x_n + \frac{a}{x_n})$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/82682) and other questions [linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/82682). A [cobweb plot](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1884302/fixed-point-iterations-for-real-functions-depending-on-fx) might help you visualize the behavior of these iterations.

Answer (score 5):

If $x_{k-1}>\sqrt a$
then
$\frac{a}{x_{k-1}} < x_{k-1}$
so
$$x_k = \frac{1}{2}(x_{k-1}+\frac{a}{x_{k-1}}) < \frac{1}{2}(x_{k-1}+x_{k-1})=x_{k-1} $$
And
$$x_k = \frac{1}{2}(x_{k-1}+\frac{a}{x_{k-1}}) \geq \frac{1}{2}2\sqrt a=\sqrt a $$
Therefore $x_k$ is always in between $x_{k-1}$ and $\sqrt a$, which means monotonic decrease.
(And therefore $\frac{a}{x_{k-1}} < x_{k-1}$ always holds.)

Now even if you picked
$x_{0}<\sqrt a$
then
$$x_1 = \frac{1}{2}(x_{0}+\frac{a}{x_{0}}) \geq \frac{1}{2}2\sqrt a=\sqrt a $$
Therefore $x_k$ goes back to the above case from $k\geq1$.

Comment: if you pick $x_0\in (0,\sqrt a)$ then $x_1>\sqrt a$ and $x_k$ decreases for $k>0$.

Comment: You're right. Thanks for correction.

Comment: I think I somewhat understand. It is pretty clear what will happen with the 1/2, and we know that $a$ and ${x_{k-1}}$ are positive, so the real question is, is if $\frac{a}{{x_{k-1}}}$ is bigger than ${x_{k-1}}$ or smaller?

Comment: Hi Lisa, I modified my answer above. Please see if it helps better.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

If a sequence is recursively defined  with a function $f$ defined on an interval $I$, it is monotonically increasing (resp. decreasing) if

- $f(I)\subset I$;
- on the interval $I$, the graph of $f$ is *above* (resp. *below*) the first bissectrix $y=x$, i.e. if $f(x)\ge x$ (resp. $f(x)\le x$) on $I$.

If furthermore, $f$ is continuous on $I$, the limit is a fixed point of $f$ on $I$.

Comment: If $x_1>\sqrt a$ ,let $x_n=(\sqrt a) coth ( v_n)$ for $n>0. $  with $v_1> 0$. Then $v_n=2^{n-1}v_1$.

Comment: What does the hell $\operatorname{coth}$ has to do here?

Comment: Just a note on a formula for $x_n$ in terms of $x_1$, and the  convergence, as clearly $coth (2^{n-1}v_1)$ tends to 1 rather quickly.