# Sequence $x_{n}=\frac{1}{2}(x_{n-1}+\frac{a}{x_{n-1}}).$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $a$ and $x_{0}$ be positive numbers, and define the sequence $\{x_{n}\}$ recursively $$x_{n}=\frac{1}{2}(x_{n-1}+\frac{a}{x_{n-1}}).$$

How to prove that the sequence converges and how to find its limit ? Actually i am thinking to prove that the sequence is monotone and bounded then limit can be find by solving the equation $x^{2}-x-a=0.$ But monotone part is dependent on the real number $a.$ Please give me simplest way to handle the problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It is not monotone, but it turns around its limit, which is $\sqrt a$. You can show the subsequences of terms of odd rank and of terms of even rank are adjacent. You should study the defining function and use the mean value inequality to show convergence.

Comment: See here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1541378/recursive-monotone-decreasing-sequence-proof-x-k-frac12-leftx-k-1?rq=1

Comment: @carmichael561 i looked at this solution i am trying different and simplest way...

Comment: @Bernard defining function is $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}(x+\frac{a}{x})$

Comment: Which is increasing after some stage...

Comment: This does not mean  a recursive sequence defined with the function is increasing.

Comment: A recursive sequence defined by an increasing function must be monotone...

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle\frac12(x_n+\frac a{x_n})\geq\sqrt a$ by AM-GM

$x_n-x_{n-1}\displaystyle=\frac12(\frac{a-{x_{n-1}}^2}{x_{n-1}})<0$

Therefore $x_n$ monotonically decreases to $\sqrt a$.

Comment: (Notice that it is possible to have $x_0<x_1$.)

Comment: Provided you prove that there exists $N$ with $x_{N}^2>a$ as the base of the induction. If $x_0^2<a$ you're in trouble, aren't you?