# Proving recursive sequence converges to $\sqrt{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Consider the sequence $x_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2} (x_n + \frac{2}{x_n})$, $x_1 = 2$. Prove that it converges to $\sqrt{2}$.

I want to show that all of $x_n$ is bounded below by $\sqrt{2}$ using induction. However, I can't see how knowing $x_n \geq \sqrt{2}$ helps show that $\frac{1}{2} (x_n + \frac{2}{x_n}) \geq \sqrt{2}$. Namely, it's not clear whether a higher value of $x_n$ produces a lower (or higher) value of $x_{n+1}$.

Edit: I am looking for a solution that does not use AM-GM (which is proven later in the text that I am reading).

Comment: I believe your sequence is monotone decreasing...Sonnhard Grauber's suggestion to use AM-GM seems like a great approach...

Comment: Show that if $x_n>\sqrt 2, \sqrt 2 <x_{n+1}<x_n$

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this is a duplicate, but I can't find it right now.

Comment: See also [Proof of Convergence: Babylonian Method $x_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}(x_n + \frac{a}{x_n})$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82682/proof-of-convergence-babylonian-method-x-n1-frac12x-n-fracax-n) (and maybe other posts [linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/82682).)

Comment: @SubhadeepDey You see the list in the [linked questions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linked-questions) in the sidebar, right? If there is too many of them to fit there, you can click on the link "see more linked questions..." The url has format as above. (You can test this basically on any question from the top of the list in the frequent tab.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I found this link most helpful: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Iterative_Process_for_Estimating_Square_Roots

Answer (score 1):

First I would like to point out that it is possible to find a duplicate for this question because it has been asked quite a few times here. So I am trying to give a fresher approach based on "completing square". Observe that:

$1)$ $x_n > 0, \forall n \geq 1$.

$2)$ $x_{n+1} - 1 = \dfrac{x_n+\dfrac{2}{x_n}}{2}-1=\dfrac{(x_n-1)^2+1}{2x_n}> 0\Rightarrow x_n > 1, \forall n \geq 1$.

$3)$$0 \leq |x_{n+1} - \sqrt{2}| = \dfrac{|x_n-\sqrt{2}|^2}{2x_n}< \dfrac{|x_n-\sqrt{2}|^2}{2} \leq|x_n - \sqrt{2}|^2\Rightarrow |x_{n+1} -\sqrt{2}|< |x_1-\sqrt{2}|^{2^n}=|2-\sqrt{2}|^{2^n}$, and apply squeeze lemma to get the limit of $\sqrt{2}$ as claimed.

Answer (score 0):

prove by induction that $$x_n>0$$ for all natural $$n$$ and then we get by AM-GM: $$x_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}(x_n+\frac{1}{x_n})\geq\sqrt{2}$$