# Prove that the sequence $a_{1}=2$ and $a_{n+1} = \frac{a_{n}}{2} + \frac{1}{a_{n}}$ for $n \geq 1$ is bounded, monotone, and find it's limit.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

For the sequence:

$a_{1}=2$ and $a_{n+1} = \frac{a_{n}}{2} + \frac{1}{a_{n}}$ for $n \geq 1$

- Prove that that the sequence is bounded.
- Prove that the sequence is monotone.
- Find the limit of the sequence.

I can do this for basic recursive sequence definitions but the presence of two fractions with sequence definitions in each one has me a bit stumped.

Comment: Use induction to prove everything (use a candidate for it limit to prove boundedness.)

Comment: Hint: solve $L=\frac{L}{2}+\frac{1}{L}$, then consider the sequence $\epsilon_n = a_n-L$. (There are two values of $L$; can you see which one is most useful?)

Comment: Closely related: [Prove that the sequence $a_{n+1} =\frac{1}{2}\left(a_{n}+\frac{c}{a_{n}}\right)$ is convergent and find its limit](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2033109/prove-that-the-sequence-a-n1-frac12-lefta-n-fracca-n-right).

Comment: Check this question closely related too: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1977236/for-a0-and-x-0-ge-a-prove-that-the-sequence-defined-as-x-n1-x-na-x-n

Answer (score 0):

Hints: You can do by induction that $1\leq a_n \leq 2$ for all $n$. Then you can use this fact that the sequence is monotone. For the limit, just do the usual thing.