# Sequence converging to $\sqrt{3}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Can someone help me with this:

pick $a_0 >0$ and define {$a_n$} by: $a_{n+1} = 2a_n/3 + 1/a_n.$

Explain why the sequence converges to $\sqrt{(3)}.$

I have calculated the first 10 elements and I can see that it's getting closer to $\sqrt{(3)}\approx1.7320$

Comment: It is a particular case of the babylonian algorithm. See (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/82682).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You first have to prove that it converges, if it converges it must converge to a fixed point:
$L=\frac{2}{3}L+\frac{1}{L}$

solving it you have, multiplying by $3L$

$3L^{2}=2L^{2}+3$

that leads to

$L^{2}=3\Rightarrow L=\sqrt{3}$ $ \quad$because your sequence is a sequence of positive numbers, because of $a_{0}>0$.

You can prove that the sequences converges by proving that it is a Cauchy sequence, for example.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I don't understand one thing. Didn't you just show that the sequences converges? why would I need to show that the sequences converges?

Comment: I show that if the sequence converges it must converge to that number.
For example, consider the sequence $x_{n+1}=3x_{n}$ with $x_{0}=1$ if the sequence converges it must converge to $L=3L\Rightarrow L=0$ but the sequence doesn't converge beaucause it diverges $\{1,3,9,27,81,...\}$ so it makes no sense saying that the sequence converges to $0$.

Comment: ah okay, but it doesn't tell us if it converges. Thank you a alot ! :)

Comment: I wrote you an example editing my comment, you are welcome! :D

Comment: I don't agree: the difficult part is the convergence and saying that it is a Cauchy sequence cannot be a good answer for the OP

Comment: He said that why converges to that, not a prove that it converges. Yes, I know that it is the difficult part.

Answer (score 1):

It's obvious that $a_n>0$.

By AM-GM $$a_{n+1}=\frac{2}{3}a_n+\frac{1}{a_n}\geq2\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}a_n\cdot\frac{1}{a_n}}=\frac{2\sqrt2}{\sqrt3}>\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}.$$
If $a_0>\sqrt3$ we obtain:
$$a_{n+1}-a_n=\frac{(\sqrt3-a_n)(\sqrt3+a_n)}{3a_n}<0$$
because $$a_{n+1}-\sqrt3=\frac{(a_n-\sqrt3)(2a_n-\sqrt3)}{3a_n}>0$$
by induction.

Thus, $a$ is a decreasing and $a_n>\sqrt3$.

Id est, there is a $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow+\infty}a_n$.

Let $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow+\infty}a_n=a$.

Thus, $a=\frac{2}{3}a+\frac{1}{a}$, which gives $a=\sqrt3$.

By the same way we can get that $a=\sqrt3$ for $0<a_0\leq\sqrt3$.

Comment: [+1] Your answer is the only good one !

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If a recursive sequence $a_{n+1}=f(a_n)$ converges, it must converge to a fixed point of $f$, that is, a number with $f(x)=x$.

(Of course, if you're being formal you need to prove that the sequence actually does converge before you can use the above.)

Comment: thank you for your answer!