# Prob. 16, Chap. 3 in Baby Rudin: $x_{n+1} = (x_n + \alpha/x_n)/2$, with $x_1 > \sqrt{\alpha}$, $\alpha > 0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, recursive-algorithms

Here is Prob. 16, Chap. 3 in the book *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* by Walter Rudin, 3rd edition:

> Fix a positive number $\alpha$. Choose $x_1 > \sqrt{\alpha}$, and define $x_2, x_3, x_4, \ldots$, by the recursion formula 
>   $$ x_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2} \left( x_n + \frac{\alpha}{x_n} \right). $$
>
> (a0 Prove that $\left\{ x_n \right\}$ decreases monotonically and that $\lim x_n = \sqrt{\alpha}$.
>
> (b) Put $\epsilon_n = x_n - \sqrt{\alpha}$, and show that 
>   $$ \epsilon_{n+1} = \frac{\epsilon_n^2}{2x_n} < \frac{\epsilon_n^2}{2\sqrt{\alpha}}$$ 
>   so that, setting $\beta = 2 \sqrt{\alpha}$, 
>   $$ \epsilon_{n+1} < \beta \left( \frac{\epsilon_1}{\beta} \right)^{2^n} \qquad (n = 1, 2, 3, \ldots). $$
>
> (c) This is a good algorithm for computing square roots, since the recursion formula is simple and the convergence is extremely rapid. For example, if $\alpha = 3$ and $x_1 = 2$, show that $\epsilon_1/\beta < \frac{1}{10}$ and that therefore 
>   $$ \epsilon_5 < 4 \cdot 10^{-16}, \qquad \epsilon_6 < 4 \cdot 10^{-22}.$$

My Attempt:

Part (a):

> As $x_1 > \sqrt{\alpha} > 0$, so $x_1^2 > \alpha > 0$, and we have 
>   $$ 
> x_1 - x_2 = x_1 - \frac{1}{2} \left( x_1 + \frac{\alpha}{x_1} \right) = \frac{1}{2} \left( x_1 - \frac{\alpha}{x_1}  \right) = \frac{ x_1^2 - \alpha }{2 x_1} > 0, 
> $$
>   which implies that $$x_1 > x_2. \tag{1} $$
>
> And, $$ x_2 - \sqrt{\alpha} = \frac{1}{2} \left( x_1 + \frac{\alpha}{x_1} \right) - \sqrt{\alpha} = \frac{1}{2} \left( \sqrt{x_1} - \frac{\sqrt{\alpha}}{\sqrt{x_1}} \right)^2 >  0,$$
>   which implies that $$ x_2 >  \sqrt{\alpha}. \tag{2} $$
>
> Suppose that, for some  natural number $n \geq 2$,  $x_n > \sqrt{\alpha} > 0$. Then we have $x_n^2 > \alpha > 0$, and so 
>   $$ x_n - x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{1}{2} \left( x_n  + \frac{\alpha}{x_n} \right) = \frac{1}{2} \left( x_n - \frac{\alpha}{x_n} \right) = \frac{x_n^2 - \alpha}{2x_n} > 0,$$
>   which implies that $x_n > x_{n+1}$.
>
> And, $$x_{n+1} - \sqrt{\alpha} = \frac{1}{2} \left( x_n  + \frac{\alpha}{x_n} \right) - \sqrt{\alpha} = \frac{1}{2} \left( x_n - 2 \sqrt{\alpha} + \frac{\alpha}{x_n} \right) = \frac{1}{2} \left( \sqrt{x_n} - \frac{\sqrt{\alpha}}{\sqrt{x_n}} \right)^2 >  0,$$
>   which implies that $x_{n+1} > \sqrt{\alpha}$.
>
> Therefore, we have $$x_1 > x_2 > \cdots > \sqrt{\alpha},$$
>   and so $\lim x_n$ exists. Let $x = \lim x_n$. Then $x \geq \sqrt{\alpha} > 0$ and 
>   $$ x = \frac{1}{2} \left( x + \frac{\alpha}{x} \right),$$
>   which implies that 
>   $$ x^2 = \alpha.  $$
>   Hence $\lim x_n = \sqrt{\alpha}$, as required.

Is this proof correct and the same as intended by Rudin?

Part (b):

> We note that 
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> \epsilon_{n+1} &= x_{n+1} - \sqrt{\alpha} \\
> &=  \frac{1}{2} \left( x_n + \frac{\alpha}{x_n} \right) - \sqrt{\alpha} \\
> &= \frac{x_n^2 - 2x_n \sqrt{\alpha} + \alpha }{2x_n} \\
> &= \frac{ (x_n - \sqrt{\alpha} )^2}{2x_n} \\
> &= \frac{\epsilon_n^2}{2x_n} \\
> &< \frac{\epsilon_n^2}{2\sqrt{\alpha}}. 
> \end{align}
> $$ 
>   Setting $\beta = 2 \sqrt{\alpha}$, we find that 
>   $$\epsilon_{n+1} < \frac{\epsilon_n^2}{\beta}. \tag{3} $$
>   Thus $$\epsilon_2 < \frac{\epsilon_1^2}{\beta} = \beta \left( \frac{\epsilon_1}{\beta} \right)^2 = \beta \left( \frac{\epsilon_1}{\beta} \right)^{2^1}. $$
>   Now suppose that for some natural number $n$, we have 
>   $$ \epsilon_{n+1} < \beta \left( \frac{\epsilon_1}{\beta} \right)^{2^n}.$$
>   Then from (3), we see that 
>   $$ \epsilon_{n+2} < \frac{\epsilon_{n+1}^2}{\beta} = \beta \left( \frac{\epsilon_{n+1} }{\beta} \right)^2  < \beta \left( \frac{ \beta \left( \frac{\epsilon_1}{\beta} \right)^{2^n} }{ \beta }  \right)^2 = \beta \left( \frac{\epsilon_1}{\beta} \right)^{2^{n+1}}, $$
>   and the required result follows by induction.

Is my proof correct and as expected by Rudin?

Part (c):

> If $\alpha = 3$ and $x_1=2$, then 
>   $\beta = 2 \sqrt{\alpha} = 2 \sqrt{3}$, and $\epsilon_1 = 2-\sqrt{3}$; so 
>   $$\frac{\epsilon_1}{\beta} = \frac{2-\sqrt{3}}{2\sqrt{3}} = \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{3} \left( 2+ \sqrt{3} \right) } = \frac{1}{6+4 \sqrt{3} } < \frac{1}{6 + 4} = \frac{1}{10} $$
>   because $1 < \sqrt{3}$.
>
> So $$ \epsilon_5 < \beta \left( \frac{\epsilon_1}{\beta} \right)^{2^4} < 4 \left( \frac{1}{10} \right)^{16} = 4 \cdot 10^{-16},$$
>   and $$\epsilon_6 < \beta \left( \frac{\epsilon_1}{\beta} \right)^{2^5} < 4 \left( \frac{1}{10} \right)^{32} = 4 \cdot 10^{-32},  $$
>   as required.

Are my calculations correct?

Comment: Your calculation looks good. You can work out Part (a) faster if study the derivative of $x-\alpha/x$. But I'm not sure derivative is available at that stage of the book.

Comment: Related: [Prove by induction for $n \geq 1$, $x_n>x_{n+1} > \sqrt{R} $ and $ x_n- \sqrt{R} \leq \frac{1}{2^n} \cdotp \frac {(x_0- \sqrt{R})^2} {x_0} $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2288597/prove-by-induction-for-n-geq-1-x-nx-n1-sqrtr-and-x-n-sqrtr/2288610).

Comment: BTW, you can solve this recursion in closed form. The hint is to re-scale so that you are finding the square root of 1, and then  look at the formula for the hyperbolic tangent of twice $x$ in terms of $tanh(x)$. This, of course, is *not* the way Rudin intended to solve the problem, but is is correct and cute.