# recursive defined sequence $a_0 =$ max{x,1} , $a_{n+1} = 1/2(a_n + x/a_n)$ .

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

$$a_0 = \max{\{x,1\}}$$ $$a_{n+1} = {\frac{1}{2} (a_n + \frac{x}{a_n})}$$

I really have some trouble understanding this recursive defined sequence. I just don't know how to calculate the n'th term or even finding $a_1$ first.

Comment: I suppose  you mean $a_{n+1}$?

Comment: oh yes I actually meant $a_{n+1}$. Sorry for the typo

Comment: This is Hero of Alexandria's method to compute a square root.

Comment: yes really! I actually have to show that this series converges to $\sqrt[2]{x}$

Comment: your second equation is different from the first?

Comment: Oh sorry, I corrected it now. And thanks!!

Comment: Hint: the sequence is monotonic.

Comment: @Msmat " I actually have to show that this series converges to $\sqrt x$" - Then why don't you say so in the problem statement? Apart from that, the sequence only converges to $\sqrt x$ for $x\ge0$. Anything else you forgot to tell us?

Comment: The result can be computed explicitly. Step 1: remove x by letting a(n) = Sqrt(x) b(n)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find the limit if it exists of $S_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2}(S_n +\frac{A}{S_n})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2384298/find-the-limit-if-it-exists-of-s-n1-frac12s-n-fracas-n)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

by the $AM-GM$ inequality you can Show that $$\frac{1}{2}\left(a_n+\frac{x}{a_n}\right)\geq \sqrt{a_n\cdot \frac{x}{a_n}}=\sqrt{x}$$

Comment: thank you that really helped me!! And It's the first time I hear from the Inequality of arithmetic and geometric means

Comment: it is $$\frac{a+b}{2}\geq \sqrt{ab}$$ for $$a\geq 0,b\geq 0$$