# Define a sequence $(a_n)$ as follows $a_1 = 1$ and for $n\geq 1,\;a_{n+1} = (-1)^n\frac{1}{2} \left(|a_n| + \frac {2}{|a_n|}\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Define  a sequence $(a_n)$ as follows $a_1 = 1$ and for $n\geq 1$ 
$$a_{n+1} = (-1)^n\frac{1}{2} \left(|a_n| + \frac {2}{|a_n|}\right)$$
then what will be it's $\limsup (a_n)$ and $\liminf (a_n)$ and $\sup(a_n)$, $\inf(a_n)$.

I tried to determine the nature of $a_{2n+1}$ and $a_{2n}$. I got $a_{2n+1}$ is increasing and $a_{2n+1} \geq \text{something}$ where $a_{2n}$ is decreasing  and $a_{2n}\leq \text{something}$. So I could not draw any conclusion.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: This sequence satisfy $a_{2n+1}\geq \sqrt 2$ and decreasing for $n\geq 1$, $a_{2n}\leq -\sqrt 2$ and increasing for $n\geq 1$, $\limsup a_n = \sqrt 2$, $\liminf a_n=-\sqrt 2$, $\sup a_n = \frac12 (\frac 32+ \frac 43)$, $\inf a_n=-\frac 32$.

Comment: To prove these, use induction.

Comment: How $(a_{2n})$ becomes increasing sequence for $n\geq 1$? Can you please elaborately explain? I calculated and I got $a_2 = -3/2$ and $a_4 = -201/104$. So   $a_2 \ge a_4$. @i707107

Comment: It is not possible for $a_{2n}$ to be less than $-3/2$. I don't think your $a_4$ is correct.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**. Taking absolute value of $$a_{n+1} = (-1)^n\frac{1}{2} \left(|a_n| + \frac {2}{|a_n|}\right)\Rightarrow 
|a_{n+1}|=\left|(-1)^n\frac{1}{2} \left(|a_n| + \frac {2}{|a_n|}\right)\right| \Rightarrow \\
|a_{n+1}|=\frac{1}{2} \left(|a_n| + \frac {2}{|a_n|}\right)$$
Using [this question and answers provided](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2384298/find-the-limit-if-it-exists-of-s-n1-frac12s-n-fracas-n/) we have
$$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} |a_n|=\sqrt{2}$$
and $(|a_n|)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ **is decreasing**.

It shouldn't be difficult to see that 
$\lim\limits_{k\rightarrow\infty} a_{2k+1}=\sqrt{2}$ and
$\lim\limits_{k\rightarrow\infty} a_{2k}=-\sqrt{2}$, because

- $0<\sqrt{2}<a_{2(k+1)+1}<a_{2k+1}$, thus $(a_{2k+1})_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ [has a limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem).
- $a_{2k}<a_{2(k+1)}<-\sqrt{2}<0$ (because $|a_{2k}|>|a_{2(k+1)}|$), thus $(a_{2k})_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ [has a limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem).

In both cases we can use the fact that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_k=a \Rightarrow \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}|a_k|=|a|$ to conclude (e.g. proof by contradiction) that:

- $\lim\limits_{k\rightarrow\infty} a_{2k+1}=\sqrt{2}$ and
- $\lim\limits_{k\rightarrow\infty} a_{2k}=-\sqrt{2}$

Comment: I can't see the last line. Can you please elaborate little bit?

Comment: @cmi updated ... let me know if you need more details!

Answer (score 0):

I think the following will help the readers to understand the solution:

We know  $$\frac{1}{2} \left(|a_n| + \frac {2}{|a_n|}\right)\ge\sqrt{|a_n| \times \frac {2}{|a_n|}}=\sqrt 2$$
$$\implies \frac{1}{2} \left(|a_n| + \frac {2}{|a_n|}\right)\ge\sqrt 2$$
Given that $~a_1 = 1~$ and for $n\geq 1$
$$a_{n+1} = (-1)^n\frac{1}{2} \left(|a_n| + \frac {2}{|a_n|}\right)$$
When $~n~$ is even, $$a_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2} \left(|a_n| + \frac {2}{|a_n|}\right)\ge\sqrt 2$$
Again when $~n~$ is odd, $$a_{n+1} = -\frac{1}{2} \left(|a_n| + \frac {2}{|a_n|}\right)\le-\sqrt 2$$
Which gives $~\lim\sup a_n=\sqrt 2~$ and $~\lim\inf a_n=-\sqrt 2~$.