# Showing that $a_1=2$ and $a_n=\frac{1}{2}(a_{n-1}+\frac{2}{a_{n-1}})$ define a decreasing bounded sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, recursion

I need to show that the sequence given by
$$a_1=2$$
$$a_n=\frac{1}{2}\Bigg(a_{n-1}+\frac{2}{a_{n-1}}\Bigg)$$
is monotonically decreasing and bounded. But every time I try, I can't make the bounds tight enough to prove it. How would I solve this?

Comment: iirc it alternates between being above the limit and below the limit

Comment: The lower bound is easy to find by AM-GM inequality. The monotonicity is determined by directly compute $a_{n+1}-a_n$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find the limit if it exists of $S_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2}(S_n +\frac{A}{S_n})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2384298/find-the-limit-if-it-exists-of-s-n1-frac12s-n-fracas-n)

Comment: @mathworker21: The sequence is monotonic. In general, when root finding with a convex function, the sequence is monotonic after the first iteration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here $a_n$ satisfies the quadratic equation $$a_n^2-(2a_{n+1})a_n+2=0$$  This equation has a real root and hence the discriminant $$4(a_{n+1}^2-2) \geq 0$$ That is,  $$a_{n+1}^2 \geq 2$$ for $n \geq 1$.

Now,
$a_{n}-a_{n+1}=a_{n}-\frac{1}{2}\Bigg( a_n+\frac{2}{a_n} \Bigg)=\frac{1}{2}\Bigg(\frac{a_n^2-2}{a_n} \Bigg)\geq 0$

for all $n \geq 1$.

Hence $$a_{n+1} \leq a_n, \forall n \geq 2$$

and so by MCT it converges to its glb!

Answer (score 3):

**Rate of Convergence**

The limit is $\sqrt2$. In fact, the convergence is quite fast, about doubling the number of digits each iteration:
$$
a_n-\sqrt2=\frac1{2a_{n-1}}\left(a_{n-1}-\sqrt2\right)^2\tag1
$$

---

**Nature of Convergence**

Note that $(1)$ guarantees that $a_n\ge\sqrt2$ for $n\ge2$. Furthermore,
$$
a_n-a_{n-1}=\frac1{2a_{n-1}}\left(2-a_{n-1}^2\right)\tag2
$$
which, because $a_{n-1}\ge\sqrt2$, guarantees that $a_n\le a_{n-1}$ for $n\ge3$.

---

Since $a_1=2\gt\sqrt2$, $a_n$ is decreasing and bounded below by $\sqrt2$.

Answer (score 1):

$a_{n+1}-a_n=\frac12\left(a_n+\frac2a_n\right)-a_n=-\frac12\left (a_n-\frac2{a_n}\right) =-\frac12\left(\frac{a_n^2-2}{a_n}\right)\le0$, since $a_n\ge\sqrt2$  (easy to see).

Hence  $(a_n)$ is monotonically decreasing.

The limit $a$  satisfies $$a=\frac12\left(a+\frac2a\right)\implies 2a^2=a^2+2\implies a^2=2$$.

Hence $a_n\to\sqrt2$.