# Prove the sequence $a_{1} = 4$, $a_{n + 1} = \frac{a_{n}}{2} + \frac{2}{a_{n}}$, $n = 1, 2, \ldots$ satisfies $a_{n} > 2$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, inequality, monotone-functions

Prove the sequence $a_{1} = 4$, $a_{n + 1} = \frac{a_{n}}{2} + \frac{2}{a_{n}}$, $n = 1, 2, \ldots$ satisfies $a_{n} > 2$

---

Let $x = a_{n}/2$.

Then $a_{n + 1} = x + 1/x$.

Define $f(x) = x + 1/x$ so that $f'(x) = -1/x^2 + 1 = 0 \implies x = 1,$ meaning that $a_{n + 1}$ has a minimum at $1 + 1/1 = 2$.

This shows $a_{n + 1} \geq 2$. But I want to show the strict bound $a_{n + 1} > 2$. Perhaps I can prove the case separately. I can't make any progress.

Comment: Prove $a_n>0$ and use $a+b\geq 2\sqrt{ab}$.

Comment: All these and a lot more are covered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2384298/find-the-limit-if-it-exists-of-s-n1-frac12s-n-fracas-n/), including linked questions ...

Answer (score 4):

AM-GM gives:
$$\frac{a}{2} + \frac{2}{a} \stackrel{a>0, a\neq 2}{>} 2\sqrt{\frac{a}{2}\cdot\frac{2}{a}} = 2$$

Edit after comments:

- Note that $a^{\star} = 2$ is a **fixpoint of the iteration** as $\frac{a^{\star}}{2} + \frac{2}{a^{\star}} = 2$.
- For **any other starting value** $a_0 > 0, a_0 \neq 2$ AM-GM tells you, that the iteration $a_{n+1} = \frac{a_n}{2} + \frac{2}{a_n}$ produces $a_{n+1} > 2$.

So, also in your specific case of $a_1 = 4$ all members of the iteration are greater than $2$.

For a direct proof that all members of the iteration are greater than $2$ you may consider

- $f(x) = \frac{x}{2} + \frac{2}{x} \Rightarrow f'(x) = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{2}{x^2}$

Now use MVT:

$$f(x) - 2 = f(x) - f(2) = f'(\xi)(x - 2) = \left(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{2}{{\xi}^2}\right) (x - 2) \stackrel{2 < \xi < x}{>} 0$$

Comment: how do i know $a \neq 2$?

Comment: @stackofhay42: If $a=2$, we t get the AM-GM $\textbf{equality}$.

Comment: Yes, if $a = 2$, we get AM-GM equality, meaning that we need to show that we cannot have $a = 2$. We never showed that it cannot be true that $a = 2$. I think that this is circular reasoning.

Comment: @RakeshBhatt: By induction, we can say that all of the terms of the given sequence are positive. We know that $a_1>0$. Suppose $a_k>0 ,\Longrightarrow a_{k+1}>0$ by the given relation.

Comment: @stackofhay42: We can also prove that by induction. $a_1\neq 2, a_k\neq 2 \Longrightarrow a_{k+1}\neq 2$ by the given relation.

Answer (score 3):

Use principle of mathematical induction,

**Basis for induction**
$$a_1>2$$

**Induction Hypothesis**
$$a_k>2$$ $$\Longleftrightarrow \frac{a_k}{2}>1$$

**Inductive step**
$$a_{k+1}=\frac{a_k}{2}+\frac{2}{a_k}>2$$
which is true by condition of equality in AM-GM inequality and induction hypothesis.

Hence proved

Hope it is helpful

Answer (score 2):

Note $a_n >0$, $n=1,2,3,.....$.

Let $n \ge 1$:

$a_{n+1}= \dfrac{a_n^2 +4}{2a_n}=$

$\dfrac{(a_n-2)^2+4a_n}{2a_n}=$

$\dfrac{(a_n-2)^2}{2a_n} + 2 \ge 2$.

(The first term  $\ge 0$, a square divided by a positive number.)

Hence

$a_{n+1} \ge 2$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 0):

Following with your reasoning, suppose $x + 1/x = 2$. Then:
$$x + 1/x = 2\implies x^2 - 2x + 1 = 0\implies x = 1.$$
But this is impossible because...

Comment: What about $a_n<2$?

Comment: @RakeshBhatt, the OP has proved $a_n > 2\implies a_{n+1}\ge 2$. Only is required excluding the equality.

Comment: Why is this impossible?

Comment: @Ekesh, because you have supposed $a_n > 2$ ($x > 1$).