# Find a set of rational numbers where $\sqrt{3}$ is the infimum. Prove it

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, supremum-and-infimum

I thought about the expansion of $\sqrt{3}$  as a series. But I didn't get anything useful. Also, I thought about a set with irrational numbers instead of rational numbers.

What is the general idea to attack this kind of problems? Since is the first one I'm doing of this type.

Comment: Hint: Consider $$(\sqrt 3,2) \cap \mathbb{Q}$$

Comment: As per [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2384298/find-the-limit-if-it-exists-of-s-n1-frac12s-n-fracas-n/), it is possible to build a sequence (and a set) for any $\sqrt{n}$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Apply Newton's Method to the function $f(x)=x^2-3$, starting with your favorite rational number that you are sure is $> \sqrt{3}$.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it.

Answer (score 3):

A simple example of a subset of $\Bbb Q$ with infimum $\sqrt3$, and which
does not presuppose existence of $\sqrt3$ or of any irrational numbers is
$$\{a\in\Bbb Q:a>0\quad\text{and}\quad a^2>3\}.$$

Comment: yep this is probably the simplest construction

Answer (score 1):

This isn't very educational, but $a_n = \text{ceil}(\sqrt{3} * 10^n)/10^n$ would work. So

$a_1 = \text{ceil}(1.73205... * 10)/10 = \text{ceil}(17.3205...)/10 = 18/10 = 1.8$
$a_2 = \text{ceil}(1.73205... * 100)/100 = \text{ceil}(173.205...)/100 = 174/100 = 1.74$
$a_3 = \text{ceil}(1.73205... * 1000)/1000 = \text{ceil}(1732.05...)/1000 = 1733/1000 = 1.733$

This would obviously work for any irrational number in the same way.

Comment: Thanks!! Now, to prove it, it seems a little weird to use the definition of infimum. Let $S$ be the set, so for every $s \in S$ we have: $s \geq \sqrt{3} + \varepsilon$ and now $a_n$ is our $s$, right?

Comment: Yep, that makes sense.