# Show that $x=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} x_{n} $ exists, where $x_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}(x_{n}+\frac{4}{x_n})$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

Let $x_0>0$, and $x_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}(x_{n}+\frac{4}{x_n})$. Show that $x=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} x_{n} $ exists.

My attempt: Let $x_0 \geq 2$, and $x_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}(x_{n}+\frac{4}{x_n})$.

1. $\{x_n\}$ is bounded.

We know that $x_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}(x_{n}+\frac{4}{x_n})\geq (x_{n} \times\frac{4}{x_n})^{1/2}=2$.

This implies that $x_{n}\geq 2$ for each $n$.

2. $\{x_n\}$ is monotonically decreasing:

Since, $x_n \geq 2$ for each $n$. Then, $x_n^2 \geq 4$. This implies $x_n \geq \frac{4}{x_n}$.

$x_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}(x_{n}+\frac{4}{x_n})\leq \frac{1}{2}(x_n+x_n)$.

This implies, $x_{n+1}<x_n$ for each $n$.

By monotone convergence theorem, $\{x_n\}$ is decreasing and bounded. This implies $\{x_n\}$ converges.

I proved this question for $x_0\geq 2$, but in question $x_0>0$. Is my idea correct for this solution, and how do I fix $x_0>0$problem.

May I need to show for $x_0<2$, the sequence $\{x_n\}$ is monotonically increasing and it converges to 2.

Anyone please give their views on this point?

Comment: Can you show if $x_0>0$ then $x_1\ge2$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner, if $x_0>0$, then $x_{1}=\frac{1}{2}(x_{0}+\frac{4}{x_0})\geq (x_0 \times \frac{4}{x_0})^{1/2}$. This implies $x_1 \geq 2$. Is it correct?

Comment: [Take a look at this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82682/proof-of-convergence-babylonian-method-x-n1-frac12x-n-fracax-n)

Comment: @Bumblebee, I see this post. Can you suggest me some improvement in my solution?

Comment: @User124356: Without assuming $x_0\ge2,$ still you can prove that $x_n\ge 2$ for all $n\ge1,$ which is enough for the conclusion. Behavior of (first) finitely many terms of a sequence has no impact on its convergence.

Answer (score 1):

Making the problem more general
$$x_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}\left(x_{n}+\frac{a}{x_n}\right)$$ rewrite it as
$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{x_n^2-a}{2x_n}$$ and recognize that this is the Newton iterative scheme for finding the zero of $f(x)=x^2-a$.

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you an alternative solution for the boundedness and monotonicity of the sequence:
Note that any term of this sequence is positive and finite (even thought  limit may not), i.e., $0\lt x_n\lt\infty.$ Therefore there is unique angle $\theta\in(0,\pi/2)$ such that $x_n=2\tan\theta$ (for a fixed $n$). Then $$x_{n+1}=\tan\theta+\cot\theta=2\csc 2\theta\ge2$$ for all $n\ge0.$ And therefore  $$x_{n+1}-x_n=\dfrac12\left(\dfrac{4}{x_n}-x_n\right)=\dfrac{(2-x_n)(2+x_n)}{2x_n}\le0$$ for all $n\ge 1.$