# Inverted pairing function without square root.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I've given a pairing function
`c = (x+y)(x+y) + x`
and asked to make `fst` and `snd` functions which return `x` and `y`, if `c` is given.

Values `x,y,c` are non-negative integers: 0,1,2,3...

The problem is, that I'm currently working with `plus` and `multiply` operations only, so `sqrt` is not allowed.

Is there a way to encode invert pairing function without `sqrt`?

This is an educational task, so if there is a way, don't tell me the actual way for a while, please.

Comment: I think this function alone cannot tell you $x$ and $y$, you are trying to get two unknowns from one known number. E.g. if $c=2$ you may have x=0 and $y=\sqrt2$ or $x=1$ and $y=0$.

Comment: Yes, there's no way to invert this.

Comment: Are $x$ and $y$ required to be integers?

Comment: Is the goal to find one solution of $f(x,y) = c$, given $c$?  That is indeed possible without square roots, only addition, multiplication and a constant.  Of course the solution is not unique.

Comment: It seems to that if we require both $x$ and $y$ to be non-negative integers then to a given $c$ of this form the solution for $x$ and $y$ is actually unique. This is because $(x+y)^2\le c<(x+y+1)^2$. Unfortunately the obvious formula for $x+y$ would then be $\lfloor\sqrt{c}\rfloor$ which is not on your list of available operations.

Comment: @SuzuHirose if c = 2, I can invert this as (1+0)*(1+0) + 1 = 2; sqrt(2) - 1 = 0

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen what about non obvious formulas? Is there a way to find nearest square number without square root?

Comment: I'm fairly sure it is possible by a recursive algorithm. But then you need some kind of division. Like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/82682/11619). Convergence speeds up if you can start from a reasonable approximation.  Otherwise there will be a number of iterations roughly one half of the length of $c$ in bits. Alternatively you could fork an approximate square root.

Comment: Division isn't required for integer square root. Just trial and error.