# Is the sequence $a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}\left(a_n+\frac{4}{a_n}\right)$ convergent without the condition $a_1>2$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

Is it possible to prove that the sequence $(a_n)_{n\ge1}$ defined as
$$a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}\left(a_n+\frac{4}{a_n}\right)$$ convergent without the condition $a_1>2$?

**Context:** Yesterday, this problem was asked on an entrance exam and I really struggled to find a solution for this. Later, I remembered that this is actually baby Rudin's exercise $16(a)$ chapter $3$. Moreover, even if it is possible to somehow prove the convergence, the question also asked to find the limit and without this condition on the first term it is impossible to decide if the limit is actually $2$ or $-2$. So, before informing the university, if somebody could also confirm my observation I would really appreciate it.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82682/proof-of-convergence-babylonian-method-x-n1-frac12x-n-fracax-n)

Comment: $\lim a_n = 2 \cdot \operatorname{sgn}(a_1)$ would be a correct answer.

Comment: @dxiv ... so if $a_1 = 0$, then ...?

Comment: @GEdgar by definition, $a_1\neq 0$.

Comment: @GEdgar If $a_1=0$ then there is no $a_2$, ergo no sequence. The point of my comment was that just because the limit may depend on the initial conditions, it doesn't mean that it can't be determined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I provide another solution than those in the [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82682/proof-of-convergence-babylonian-method-x-n1-frac12x-n-fracax-n). With this solution, we can have closed-form formula for $a_n$.

If $a_1$ is negative then all $(a_n)_n$ are negative, and it suffices to denote $b_n= -a_n$.

So, we can suppose that $a_1$ are positive and so are all $(a_n)_n$. We notice that
$$a_{n+1}-2 = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{a_n-2}{\sqrt{a_n}}  \right)^2 \tag{1}$$
$$a_{n+1}+2 = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{a_n+2}{\sqrt{a_n}}  \right)^2\tag{2}$$

From $(1),(2)$ we have

$$\frac{a_{n+1}-2 }{a_{n+1}+2 }= \left(\frac{a_n-2}{a_n+2}  \right)^2=...=\left(\frac{a_1-2}{a_1+2}  \right)^{2^n} \tag{3}$$

From $(3)$ you deduce the closed form solution of $a_n$.

From that, it's easy to show that, $a_n  \to 2$ when $n\to +\infty$.

Return back to the case where $a_1 <0$ at the beginning, we can prove that $a_n = - b_n\to -2$ when $n\to +\infty$

Comment: I suggest you post this answers to the linked duplicate instead (with some changes, of course) That post is more popular.

Comment: @ArcticChar Yes, I just post it in the post you mentionned.