# Explanations of the Euler's continued fractions to compute exponential

Tags: exponential-function, continued-fractions

After looking for explanations of the Euler's continued fractions to compute exponential on internet and after reading [Euler's explanations about](http://kb.osu.edu/dspace/bitstream/handle/1811/32133/Wyman.pdf?sequence=1), I still don't understand how Euler find this continued fraction :

$$e=2+\dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{1}{2+\dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{1}{4+\dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{1}{6+\ddots}}}}}}}}$$
I understand how Euler get continued fractions to compute squares but not for exponential. Maybe I have missed something, but I really need to understand. So thanks for your help.

Comment: (slightly) related: [Continued fraction for $\frac{1}{e-2}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/3382/)

Comment: Consider $\frac{e+1}{e-1}$