# Continued fraction $1 + \frac 2{3 + \frac 4 {5 + \cdots}} = \frac 1 {\sqrt{e} - 1}$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, continued-fractions

I saw [this link](https://wakara.co.jp/mathlog/%E4%B8%AD%E5%AD%A62%E5%B9%B4%E7%94%9F%E3%81%A7%E6%95%B0%E6%A4%9C1%E7%B4%9A%E5%90%88%E6%A0%BC%EF%BC%81%E3%80%80%E5%8F%B2%E4%B8%8A%E6%9C%80%E5%B9%B4%E5%B0%91%E5%90%88%E6%A0%BC%E8%80%85%E3%81%AE%E8%8F%85) (written in Japanese) and found an interesting problem:

Calculate $1 + \frac 2{3 + \frac 4 {5 + \cdots}}$.

The link provides the answer ($\frac 1 {\sqrt e - 1}$) and a hint that one uses Maclaurin series, but doesn't provide a detailed answer.

Can someone explain this equality? If possible, can someone also calculate

1. $1^2 + \frac {2^2}{3^2 + \frac {4^2} {5^2 + \cdots}}$ and
2. $1^n + \frac {2^n}{3^n + \frac {4^n} {5^n + \cdots}}$?

These two are also in the link, and answers of them are not provided and seem unsolved.

Answer of [Continued fraction for $\frac{1}{e-2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3382/continued-fraction-for-frac1e-2) might help.

Comment: See [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_continued_fraction_formula)

Comment: The first question was easy: just substitute -1/2 for z in [the link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_continued_fraction_formula#The_exponential_function). Thank you.